# Selenium cannot run the same code block that selects values from 2 drop-down menus

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div/span[contains(., 'category' )]"))).click()       # Opens the Drop-down menu
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//mat-option/span[contains(., 'X' )]"))).click()   # Clicks on the specific option

sleep(2)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div/span[contains(., 'sub-category' )]"))).click()   # Opens the Drop-down menu
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//mat-option/span[contains(., 'Y')]"))).click()   # Clicks on the specific option
```

There is a webpage that has 2 drop-down menus.

When I run this code block in Jupyter Notebook environment, it perfectly performs what it needs to do. However, if I change `X` and `Y` values with a different set of values and re-run, it throws `TimeoutException`

Website: https://visa.vfsglobal.com/en/en/pol/login

Why it happens?

Comment: Pleas share the url of the webpage you are using.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed Edited now, by adding the URL